# I am writing a unit test on my extension method which will check if ValidIssuer and ValidAudiences is setting correctly but its failing?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, authentication

I am adding AddAuthanication().jwtBearer()  and passing ValidIssuer and ValidAudiencs to TokenValidationParameters for checking perpouse I write a unit test to check if this options are passing correctly but test failing and I checked that in TokenValidationParameters ValidIssuer and ValidAudiencs is null, why its not passing ?

```
[Fact]
public void AddKeycloakAuthentication_ConfiguresAuthentication()
{
    // Arrange
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    var jwksJson = "{ \"keys\": [{ \"kid\": \"key-id\", \"kty\": \"RSA\", \"n\": \"base64-encoded-modulus\" }] }";

    // Mock HttpClient
    var httpClientMock = new Mock<IHttpClientWrapper>();
    httpClientMock
        .Setup(client => client.GetStringAsync(It.IsAny<Uri>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(jwksJson);

    services.AddKeycloakAuthentication(options =>
    {
        // Configure the KeycloakAuthenticationOptions here
        options.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://example.com");
        options.Realms = "testrealm";
        options.ValidAudiences = new string[] { "audience1", "audience2" };
        options.ValidIssuer = "https://example.com/auth/realms/testrealm";
    }, httpClientMock.Object);

    services.AddAuthentication("Keycloak")
        .AddJwtBearer("Keycloak", options =>
        {
            // Configure additional options if needed
        });

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    // Act
    JwtBearerOptions jwtBearerOptions = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<JwtBearerOptions>>().Value;

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(jwtBearerOptions);
    Assert.NotNull(jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters);

    // Check TokenValidationParameters
    Assert.Equal(new string[] { "audience1", "audience2" }, jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences);
    Assert.Equal("https://example.com/auth/realms/testrealm", jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer);
}
```